# Solr, OutOfMemoryErrors and heap not freed

Tags: solr, heap-memory

I have a SolrCloud composed by three Solr instances (9Gb heap) each hosted by a dedicated host (12Gb RAM).

Currently we have a collection with 150+ million documents and growing. In times we do lots of queries I see (what I think is) a strange behavior in JVM:

[Solr heap growth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIxgy.png)

At the plateau all instances raised `OutOfMemoryErrors` and as I observe GC times as the heap goes up, I see what I think is almost no GC at all:

[Solr JC times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gUAW.png)

I've configured all instances to use GC1 and followed the documentation regarding heap for a well configured Solr instance, yet I feel something is really wrong here.

Can somebody help me understand why it appears that no GC occurs as queries are made (maybe some cache tunning or memory leak)?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just in case someone else hit this issue, it was indeed some cache tunning needed for my particular use.

TL;DR:

Tuning of the `filterCache` in my collection did the trick! :D

---

How did I troubleshoot it:

1. Identified with monitoring the period when the issue occurred (thanks Prometheus and Grafana!)
2. Identified what applications were doing at that time
3. Tried to reproduce the behavior in a managed condition
4. Once I had the ability to trigger the problem anytime I wanted, I've taken heap dumps of Solr JVM every three minutes as the heap increased
5. With VisualVM I analysed what objects didn't get cleaned up by the GC
6. So I searched the referencing objects for the list on the previous item

All this to find out that FastLRUCache objects contained `int[]` arrays. Googling for "solr heap growth FastLRUCache" I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021240/1018851).

So, as now we have 250 million documents in this collection, all I had to do was tune the `filterCache` setting from its origin `512` value to a much lower number like `20` or so.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.