# unit of size param in filterCache

Tags: solr

I am reading a book Solr and have reached a section explaining filterCache and it's config. This is an example configuration:

```
<filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
             size="512"
             initialSize="512"
             autowarmCount="0"/>
```

I am puzzled by the unit (entry) of `size`, `initialSize` and `autowarmCount`?

The docs say:

```
       size - the maximum number of entries in the cache
       initialSize - the initial capacity (number of entries) of
           the cache.  (see java.util.HashMap)
       autowarmCount - the number of entries to prepopulate from
           and old cache.
```

If I am reading this correctly, an entry is key value pair of `category:book` (or `category:car`) and the documents matching the filter. It has nothing to do with the actual size of cache in MB. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Correct; the size will roughly be `<num of docs in index> * <size>` bits. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999904/solr-filter-cache-fastlrucache-takes-too-much-memory-and-results-in-out-of-mem